# Problem with file submiting

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, file-io

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://site.com/img">
File: <input type="file" name="file" id="abc" /><br/>  
ID: <input type="text" name="someId" value="123"/>
<input id="submitFormButton" type="submit" value="Upload" name="Upload"> 
</form>

<input type="button" id="btnEditAvatar" value="fakeButton"/>

$("#btnEditAvatar").bind("click", function () { $("#abc").trigger("click"); });
$("#abc").change(function() { $("#submitFormButton").trigger("click"); });
```

Problem occurs in **IE only**.
When choose file by pressing on "abc" button it works(after closing file dialog, file is uploaded), but when I press on "btnEditAvatar" button, nothing is happened after closing file diaog.

I've tried to use "click" function instead of "change". I've tried to call it with "setTimeout" function and I also tried to use "onpropertychange" event handler.

http://jsfiddle.net/streamcode9/hAnbQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead if trying to click the submit button, why not just submit the form?

```
$("#abc").change(function() { $(this).closest('form').submit() });
```

Comment: It does not work. There are no errors and form is not submited.

Comment: Is it possible to open file dialog after clicking on "fakeButton" button and submit form after closing? I need something like that. http://jsfiddle.net/streamcode9/3mcCR/

Comment: No, file inputs run in a secure mode to prevent scripts from trying to access the local file system.

Answer (score 0):

try either of these:

```
$("#btnEditAvatar").bind("click", function () { $("#submitFormButton").trigger("click"); });
$("#abc").change(function() { $("#submitFormButton").trigger("click"); });
```

This binds it to submit.

```
$("#btnEditAvatar").bind("click", function () { $("#abc").trigger("change"); });
$("#abc").change(function() { $("#submitFormButton").trigger("click"); });
```

this binds it to change which triggers the submit click

Comment: Can I see the page? or can you see any errors in the error console. also, if your second line works, you should be able to copy it and change '#abc' to '#btnEditAvatar' and 'change' to 'click'

Comment: There may be another issue then as this code is basic, and the post below is what I was about to recommend to simplify it.